# How do you get EntityFramework 6.1 to support Filtering and two way Binding like adapter.Fill(table) does?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get EntityFramework 6.1.1 to return an ObserveableCollection or an IEnumerable that supports both Filtering and Sorting and Binding (Two-way) in a WinForm. I am not at all concerned what format the Entity is as the end as long as it is Bindable and supports Filtering and Sorting. I guess how adapter.Fill(table) worked but just with EntityFramwork as the backbone.
If have tried returning a _context.Orders.Local.ToBindingList();
But the associated OrderDetails entities are not Sortable nor can I Filter them.
If I attach a Where expression to Orders it Converts it to IEnumerable and I cannot Filter them nor can I edit them now.
Would a generic repository pattern help in this case? If so, would you please respond with code-examples?

Here is my simplified Order Class:

```
    public class Orders
    {
        public Orders()
        {
            Details = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int OrderId {get; set}
        public int CustomerId {get; set;}
        public decimal OrderTotal { get; set;}
        public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}

        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetails> Details {get; set;}
        public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}
    }
```

I have a ClassLibrary with the following three methods I have tried. The InitDatabase() Method Loads the Entities if they are not already Loaded.

Method #1:

```
    public static ObservableCollection<ZSA_TransactionDetail> GetAllDetailsAsObservableCollection()
    {
        InitDatabase();
        return NContext.ZSA_TransactionDetail.Local;
    }
```

Method #2:

```
    public static ICollection<ZSA_TransactionDetail> GetAllDetailsAsICollection(int orderNumber = 1022)
    {
        InitDatabase();
        ICollection<ZSA_TransactionDetail> iCollection = null;

        ObservableCollection<ZSA_TransactionHeader> headers = NContext.ZSA_TransactionHeader.Local;
        ZSA_TransactionHeader myHeader = headers.FirstOrDefault(i => i.intTransactionNumber == orderNumber);
        if (myHeader != null)
        {
            iCollection = myHeader.ZSA_TransactionDetail;
        }

        if (iCollection != null)
            Debug.WriteLine("iCollection Record Count was: " + iCollection.Count);
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("iCollection was null");

        return iCollection;
    }
```

Method #3:

```
    public static BindingList<ZSA_TransactionDetail> GetAllDetailsAsBindingList(int orderNumber = -1)
    {
        InitDatabase();
        if (orderNumber != -1 && IsValidTransaction(orderNumber))
        {
            BindingList<ZSA_TransactionDetail> details = NContext.ZSA_TransactionDetail.Local.ToBindingList();
            var myDetails =
                details.Where(i => i.intTransactionNumber == orderNumber) as BindingList<ZSA_TransactionDetail>;
            if (myDetails != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Number of details: " + myDetails.Count);
                return myDetails;
            }
            throw new Exception("Did not find any details");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Not a valid Transaction Number");
        return NContext.ZSA_TransactionDetail.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
```

My Form_Load Event looks like this when calling Method #2:

```
    private void FormPick_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ICollection<ZSA_TransactionDetail> data = Library.GetAllDetailsAsICollection(_transactionNumber);

        PickingBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;

        PickingBindingSource.DataSource = data;

        Debug.WriteLine("Supports Filter: " + PickingBindingSource.SupportsFiltering);

        PickingGridView.DataSource = PickingBindingSource;

        ApplyFilter();
    }
```

All three Methods report SupportsFiltering false.

Comment: Anything should be sortable if it's enumerable as this is where the linq extension methods are targeted, when you say it's not sortable, what have you tried?

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Thank you @Charleh. As you pointed out yes, they can be sorted but now not editable. I need to be able to edit them in a DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: to better explain**
The local property on the context set is an observable collection.

> Would a generic repository pattern help in this case?

Yes , this is a common pattern in such case.
So using a generic `Repository<T>` pattern.
Use a Method like:

```
 public ObservableCollection<TPoco> Local {
        get { return Context.Set<TPoco>().Local; }
    }
```

This gives you access to context loaded objects for the POCO in question.

Use your normal approach To populate prior to accessing the Local objects.

Also check out `Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = <bool>;`

try a simple test case where you load a few objects.
Then access the objects via the local property, make a simple change or 2
and `SaveChanges()`.

Then try with the collection bound.

Comment: Could you expand your answer just a bit more? Where am I putting this Property?